# crontab remove file which's path contain %

Tags: linux, shell, cron

want to delete `indexInitializer.log` file. so define crontab with this:`0 3 * * * rm -rf /alidata1/setupTms3/jboss-eap-6.4/%LOG_DIRECTORY%/tire2e/indexInitializer.log.*`

However, all files in the folder `/alidata1/setupTms3/jboss-eap-6.4/` were deleted during actual operation.

check cron log found : `Jul 21 17:00:01 tmsprod4 CROND[26461]: (root) CMD (rm -rf /alidata1/setupTms3/jboss-eap-6.4/)`, Why is the suffix(`%LOG_DIRECTORY%/tire2e/indexInitializer.log.*`) missing during execution.  There is no problem with running directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to backslash the `%` character, so:

```
0 3 * * * /bin/rm -rf /alidata1/setupTms3/jboss-eap-6.4/\%LOG_DIRECTORY\%/tire2e/indexInitializer.log
```

From `man 5 crontab`:

> The 'sixth' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
> run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to  a  newline  or  %  character,  will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file.
> Percent signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the  first %  will  be  sent  to  the command as standard input.  There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "".